# Auto-Login on ubuntu-mate

Tags: command-line, login, mate

I have a problem with auto-login on Ubuntu-Mate on ARM (RPi). I can achieve this when using the GUI, but I need the Pi to auto-login into CLI, which I could easily set in Raspbian by using raspi-config.

There is a similar problem at [Auto-login enable on turn on system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202230/auto-login-enable-on-turn-on-system) that provided a solution that did not work for me, as my ubuntu-mate on ARM is using GDM3 display manager and not the lightdm as suggested in the other post. I changed the GDM3 config file, which I found here https://techpiezo.com/linux/enable-or-disable-automatic-login-in-ubuntu-20-04/

However, it still did not auto-login to command line, it just sits at the cli "Login:". I presume the display manager (GDM3) is just for the GUI, so until I can resolve the cli auto login, I will have to use the GUI to auto-start the application on this headless Pi.

Any suggestions would be welcomed..

Comment: Hi @Phil. Can you edit your question so that one won't need to navigate away to another  link to understand what exactly you are asking. At least outline your question first, then add the links to the solutions you tried and they failed

Comment: Good point kelvinelove. My original post was a reply to the other question (linked) but my response was bounced as being "not an answer", so I had to create this new question. The moderator suggested that I linked to the original question for context.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: the auto login using the gui IS for logging into the desktop. https://askubuntu.com/a/819154/15811 will do what you want.