# Is there any way to press enter via bashrc with echo and ASCII character when the computer boots?

Tags: bash

I have installed in my Raspberry Pi ubuntu server with ubuntu mate desktop. My problem is that i have chosen to boot without password but it ask the password, if i press enter will be enter to the system. So I think if there's a way to press enter from bashrc file. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is it having you press Enter to boot?  Close to the desktop load or right at the beginning when it boots?  If it is right at the beginning adding something to your bashrc will not make a difference.  Is there a way that you can add to your question showing where it is prompting you to press Enter?

Comment: I edit my question. I want to press enter in the point that it asks the password from the user

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto-login enable on turn on system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202230/auto-login-enable-on-turn-on-system)

Comment: No, i did all these things. I need to press the key enter from bash that's all I need.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am trying to figure out what you are asking.  Do you need to type in a command to launch the MATE Desktop and you want to bypass pressing Enter at the command prompt to launch it?  If so, you can just make it so that the MATE Desktop starts automatically.  Usually done with a command of `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` so it launches MATE automatically.